# Custom string types in Go

Tags: go

How can I create a custom type in Go that is restricted to a certain list of string values? e.g.

```
type Suit = "Spade" | "Diamond" | "Club" | "Heart"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go does not have Algebraic data types [(ADT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type). What you want is "sum" type in ADT. For example there are enums in Swift and Rust to support them.
Go does not have generics(yet); there is no Option, Result type as well.

While what you want to do can be achieved using different ways in Go, I like using const instead of empty interface or type check or reflection. I think const would be more faster and readable. Here is how I will go. You can return the string from method instead of printing if that is what you want.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Suit int

const (
    Spade Suit = iota + 1
    Diamond
    Club
    Heart
)

type Card struct {
    suit Suit
    no   int
}

func (c *Card) PrintSuit() {
    switch c.suit {
    case Spade:
        fmt.Println("Its a Spade")
    case Diamond:
        fmt.Println("Its a Diamond")
    case Club:
        fmt.Println("Its a Club")
    case Heart:
        fmt.Println("Its a Heart")
    default:
        fmt.Println("Unknown!")
    }
}

func main() {

    c := Card{suit: Diamond}

    c.PrintSuit()

}
```

You can accept external func in  methods like `PrintSuit` if the processing logic is external.

Comment: This route doesn't do anything to prevent a `Suit` value from being assigned an unwanted value (e.g. `suit = Suit(123)`), but it is perhaps the most appropriate solution for this kind of use case.

Comment: Unwanted values are taken care in switch conditions. The important thing is suit starts from  `iota + 1` instead of just iota as I want to avoid giving value 0 to any suit type because that is default case when someone does `Card{}`. Also you need to take care of proper initialization in in NewCard function that produces a right Card{}.

Comment: `This route doesn't do anything to prevent a Suit` you can consider having a non exported type with only exported values.

Answer (score -2):

Define a type alias for `string` i.e., `Suit`. The `Suit` is a type whose underlying type is a string.

Now, create some constants of type Suit. In the following ode, `Spade`, `Diamond`, `Club`, `Heart` are of type Suit. Now the function in which you want the parameter to be restricted to some input (which is not possible); but what you can do it to restrict it accept the `Suit` type only, and pass any of the `const` variable created.

```golang
// Define new type alias for string
type Suit  string

const (
    Spade Suit   = "Spade"
    Diamond Suit = "Diamond"
    Club Suit    = "Club"
    Heart Suit   = "Heart"
)

// function f only accepts parameter of type "Suit" 
func f(s Suit)  {
    fmt.Println(s)
}

func main()  {
    // Call the function f with Spade
    f(Spade)
}
```

Comment: this isn't how you make data types with restricted values, also as @Abhijit_K said go doesn't suppourt it.

Comment: this (`type Suit  string`) is not a type alias, type alias has a specific syntax with specific behavior. This is a regular type declaration https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations

Comment: @whitespace It's already written in the answer that it's not actually possible.

Comment: The main point is to have editor support and this just allows me to type anything into the function. I would not recommend this.